# username and password program using python 3.4

Tags: python

The text file is displayed like this:

apple,crumble

Where apple is the username and crumble is password, separated by the comma.

I need a password and username system to make sure the user is authorised. so far I've done this:

```
username = input("Please enter your name. ")
print("Your username has been created and is", username)
password = input("Now please create a password. ")

file = open("Login.txt","a")
file.write (username)
file.write (",")
file.write (password)
file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

It saves the user username and password in a text file.
So how do I create a login system that checks for the username and the password from the text file line by line?

For example if a user enters a password and username located on line 7, the program needs to check all previous lines until it finds the input that the user has entered.

> I can only use python, no other programs such as Pandas or CMD.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with? Do you know how to read a file?

Comment: *"i can only use python, no other programs such as pandas..."*. Pandas is a module in Python, not a new language or a program.

Comment: Hint: 1. declare a variable loginok=False 2. read the file one line at a time 3. for each line, strip the newline and split on comma (`,`) 4. first field is a username and second a password 5. if both match, set loginok to True and exit from loop Then after the loop, loginok tells you whether login was successful.

Comment: The code to create to the password file is mostly redundant to the textual description and is no substitute for code attemtping to solve the query problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create dictionary first from that file then you can easily check username exsits then match the password as well. In here u need unique usernames(login system need it)

```
dict = {}
with open("Login.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (userName, password) = line.split(',')
       dict[userName] = password
```

Then check if user name exists here. Then check password as well like below

```
if enteredName in dict:
    if dict[enteredName] == enteredPassword:
       print("login success")
    eles:
       print("wrong password")
else:
   print("login failed")
```